# jdk not found while installing android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I have installed jdk for 64 bit but still when I start installing android studio, it shows JDK not found or browse the path where it is installed. I browse
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40 but then also it shows error this not we are looking to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is no permission to android studio installation process to access the path where the JDK is installed. Try to run the installation as administrator.

Answer (score 0):

Open the command line and run:

```
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40"
SET PATH=$PATH:"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_40\bin"
```

Regards

Comment: Nopes this doesnt work..plss help been trying to make it from last 4 hours.

Comment: what happens when you open the console and type commands javac and java ?

also when you browse to that directory, after installing studio, can you browse to the bin folder within it?

Comment: when i enter the command and press "enter" it just passes to next line for another command